# Github merge multiple files into single compressed master file

Tags: jquery, css, github, git-merge

One of our sites has a bunch of separate CSS files & JS files being called and I want to optimise it all into a single CSS & a single JS file.

Someone mentioned you can setup Github to do this by having your files separate in GitHub repositories and it will build a new single master file that has all the code compressed and updating any of the single files will update the master file.

This might sound easy to people who use Github but I've only used Github for storing code and pieces in the past and never really done much else with it. I've tried looking for information on this and I've found stuff about merging repositories/branches but it doesn't seem to do all of what we wanted.

Can someone help with what I need to do? or point me in the direction of a guide for setting up and doing what we need described above? Alternatively is there something that can do this outside of Github?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Isn't it easier just do to it yourself with for example gulp?

Comment: Hi, Thanks I did explain I was new to this and looking for suggestions on ways to do this (Github was just something someone mentioned to look at). Where can I get this gulp and is there guides for setting it up and using it?

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer: I don't know how it's done with Github so I recommended
>   gulp

**What is gulp?**

*Gulp is a task runner built on Node.js and npm, used for automation of time-consuming and repetitive tasks involved in web development like minification, concatenation, cache busting, unit testing, linting, optimization, etc.*

**Why use gulp in your case?**

It's nice to have a lot of different js and css files to keep a good overview of your project. Migrating this all to one file is good for performance but a pain in the ass to change it later. With gulp you can minify your css or js to one file but still keep the original files.

**How to use gulp?**

Gulp is widely documented throughout the internet. So as long it's not clear, i'm just giving some useful links:

*Set up*

https://riptutorial.com/gulp/topic/1341/getting-started-with-gulp

*Minify JS*

https://riptutorial.com/gulp/topic/4397/minifying-js

*Minify CSS*

https://riptutorial.com/gulp/example/25432/minifying-css

Once minified, add to your repo and change your references to all css/js files to this js/css file. And you are done!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I've up-marked it for the effort and information provided and if it works for this case I'll mark it as the answer (it may just take me some time to sort it) thanks :)